# node-sass vulnerability and npm audit

Tags: npm, audit, node-sass

I have projects to maintain that use node-sass npm module.

Since node 10.x, there is a tool (called `npm audit`) that is run every time we do a `npm install`. This seems to be a good tool for preventing vulnerability issues.

My problem is that the node-sass module has vulnerabilities. I saw that the maintainers of the project do not want to fix the issues with bad reasons.
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2262

People maintaining popular module like node-sass should correct as soon as possible the vulnerability issues, but unfortunately they don't.

I am not an expert in Security, so I prefer to rely on what indicates npm and not use anymore dependencies that print messages that let you think your software is crap.

But I like so much SASS for coding CSS that I would like to give it a chance to keep it.
Any idea for removing these vulnerability messages while keeping the project safe and not reducing developer experience ?

Comment: Either: fix the vulnerability and PR it; find a different library for preprocessing CSS; or write one yourself.

Comment: Or just upgrade to 4.9.1: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2355

Comment: Apparently, the maintainer does not accept the PR regarding it. I would like as well a solution largely adopted. Not necessarely mine. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: If you're asking for another library, that's off topic here. Otherwise, it's unclear what your question is: those are your options, pick one, or ignore the audit messages.

Comment: npm i node-sass@4.9.1 : found 5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

Comment: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/
TL;DR: `npm audit` isn't a very good tool because it also warns for issues that aren't a problem in production code.

Answer (score 3):

This security issue is mainly irrelevant to **node-sass** since it never sees any exposure to your live code.

**node-sass** runs on hosts normally used for development and usually are not visible in a public network.

You normally will use **node-sass** to pre-compile SCSS into CSS and vulnerabilities will not impact the resulting CSS code.

These warnings are relevant if you run the node.js server as a backend which is *normally* not the case. (or never the case)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use dart-sass.  It has no vulnerability issues.

https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader